# "Out of Bounds" CAD-originated shapefiles unable to georeference

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, extents, autocad-map

I'm trying to import several polyline files from an AutoCad drawing into ArcMap. I keep running into an "out of bounds" error when trying to georeference the CAD layers to where they should be.

I don't believe the CAD files have a coordinate system. The shapefiles are located in the middle of the wilderness some 300k meters away from the expected location. When trying to georeference them, selecting Adjust does nothing and the Link Table shows 0 for the X and Y regardless of where I place the links.

I've tried using the Copy Features to Feature Class tool with environments set to use Union of Inputs for the extent and disable M and Z values. The resulting line files are also unable to be georeferenced.

When I try to edit, select all, and then Move using a set X,Y point, I'm told the file can't be moved because it is out of bounds.

I've tried creating new GDB's with a set coordinate system..but that didn't work either.

What could I try next?

I'm trying to place the CAD files into NAD_1983 State Plane MO East in Feet. I am not sure of the XY coordinates of the CAD file.

Edit: The original CAD file has no coordinate system, per the surveying company. I have a folder of exported shapefiles from the CAD file that I cannot georeference because any resulting feature classes made from those shapefiles are "out of bounds."

Comment: Odds are, the coordinate reference is incorrect. Please [Edit] the question to specify the range of X/Y values in the CAD layer and the exact spatial reference you are trying to assign.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the range of x/y values in the CAD layer. Do you mean the extent it has once added to ArcMap?

Comment: Before and after are the same thing, I would hope.

Comment: If you don't know the source coordinate system, it will be difficult to get the data into the correct position (if it's not in any coordinate system, it might be impossible).